# intermitent JSON results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Good evening,

I am working on a form processor that determines which form was sent to it processes and emails / sometimes needs to return results to my jquery for further client side processing. The issue i am running into is that the first time the script is run it returns the array, but any subsequent runs return no data.

**The PHP**

```
    switch ($form){
    case 'cta':
        echo json_encode(array('callback' => 'cta'));
        //echo"";
        break;
    case "questionaire":

        echo json_encode(array('callback' => 'quetionaire'));
        break;
    case "contact":

        echo json_encode(array('callback' => 'contact'));
}
```

**The Jquery**

```
function doEmail(form){
$.ajax({
   data: $(form).serialize(),
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'core/process.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
    $(form +' input, textarea').each(function(){$(this).val("") })
    $('#lightbox').fadeOut(600)
    $('#responder').fadeOut(600)
    alert('form name '+ data.callback);

   }
 })     
}
function inputProcessor(event, form){
var $name = $(form + ' input#name').val();
var $phone = $(form + ' input#phone').val();
var $email = $(form + ' input#email').val();
var $msg = $(form + ' textarea#msg').val();

var $i = 0;
var $i1 = 0;
$(form +' [req=yes]').each(function() {
    console.log('step 1')
        $i++;
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
        if(!$(this).val().length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ffd7d7');                
        }
    });
    $(form +' [req=yes]').each(function() {
        console.log('step 2')
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            event.preventDefault();
            $i1++;                
        }
    });
    //if($i1 === $i){            
        var result = regex.test($email)
        console.log('step 3')
        if (result === true){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('Testing Email')
            doEmail(form);
        }else{
            $(form +' input#email').css('background-color', '#ffd7d7');                
        }                
    //}
}
```

It should also be noted that this site never refreshes all the content resides in hidden divs that are revealed when the "page" link is clicked.

Thanks in advance

Edit "I actually have to exit the browser and restart it in order to get a new array"

Edit 2

**1 of 3 Forms**

```
<form id="cta"  method="post">
<input type="text" req="yes" id="name" class="input"   name="name" placeholder="Full Name"/><br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="phone" class="input" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="email" class="input" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/><br>     
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="cta">
<span id="submit_btn">Submit entry</span>
</form>
```

**2 of 3 Forms**

```
<form id="contact_form" class=contact_form method="post">                            
<input type="text" req="yes" id="name" class="input3" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<br>  <br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="phone" class="input3" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
<br><br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="email" class="input3" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<br><br>
<textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Type your message here" class="input3" rows="4"></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="contact">
<span class="contact_button" id="SubmitContact"><div id="contact_submit">Send message</div></span>
</form>
```

**3 of 3 forms**

```
<form id="response" class=form1  method="post">

<input type="text" req="yes" id="name" class="input2" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="phone" class="input2" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
<br>
<input type="text" req="yes" id="email" class="input2" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<br>
<textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Type your message here" class="input2" rows="4"></textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="questionaire">
<span class="submit_button" id="Submit"><div id="submit">Send message</div></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Ideally the form code needs to be seen here to help. Make sure that the form submits the correct information first. If its returning blank then maybe the switch isnt hitting anything, add a default: onto the switch to see whats being sent.

Comment: Form code added, Thanks for the response!

Comment: Add a `default: echo json_encode(....` to make sure you catch it on the php side. Also, could you give us the code calling your `doEmail`.

Comment: added in the default as suggested and uploaded the function that calls doEmail, seems that after the first run through default is the only case firing

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i answered my own question after getting a night of sleep and realizing that i needed to unset the form variable.

```
 var result = regex.test($email)
        console.log('step 3')
        if (result === true){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('Testing Email')
            formId = $(form +' input#formId').val();
            if(formId === 'cta'){
                $('#cta_form').children().fadeOut(600)
                window.location.href = 'docs/medical-alert.pdf';
            }
            doEmail(form, formId);
        }else{
            $(form +' input#email').css('background-color', '#ffd7d7');                
        }
        $(form).remove()
```